# $\frac{x}{4} = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{7}{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please explain to me what's wrong here?

$\cfrac{x}{4} = \cfrac{y}{x} = \cfrac{7}{y}$

So $$\cfrac{x^2}{4} = y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y  = \sqrt{7x}$$

Hence $$\cfrac{x^2}{4} =\sqrt{7x}$$

With a solution of $x = 2.57$

But $$\cfrac{2.57^2}{4} \neq \sqrt{7 (2.57)}$$

Comment: Then it would seem "with a solution of $x=2.57$" is not actually correct. How did you get that value?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You rolled back in the middle of my edit. Please show some patience. The slash form obscures  the innate symmetry.

Comment: Why take square roots like this.  Just $x^2=4y$ and $y^2=7x$ enable you to solve - note that in the original equations we can't divide by $0$ so that $xy\neq 0$ and we can divide by either.

Comment: There are other potential answers in the complex plane as well.

Comment: @Hyperion e.g. choose $\,a\,$ to be a *nonreal* cube root of $7/4$ in my answer.

Comment: I added a remark to my answer about the natural generalization as a telescoping product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\neq 2.57$. You want to solve for $x^2/4 = \sqrt{7x}$, which corresponds to solving the polynomial equation $x^4/16 - 7x = 0$, which has a real and nontrivial zero at $\sqrt[3]{112}$. Hence, $x = \sqrt[3]{112}$ and $y = (112)^{2/3} / 4$. You can check that this in fact, is a solution to your system.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ Multiplyimg $\,\overbrace{ \dfrac{\color{#c00}x}{4} = \dfrac{\color{#0a0}y}{\color{#c00}x} = \dfrac{7}{\color{#0a0}y}}^{\Large a}\,\Rightarrow\,a^{\large 3} = \dfrac{7}4$

hence  $\, x = 4a,\ \ y = xa = 4a^2,\ \ 7 = ya = 4a^3\  \ \checkmark$

**Remark** $ $ This *telescoping product* view works generally

$\,\overbrace{ \dfrac{\color{#c00}{x_1}}{x_0} = \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{x_2}}{\color{#c00}{x_1}} = \dfrac{x_3}{\color{#0a0}{x_2}}= \,\cdots\, = \dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}} }^{\Large a}\ \Rightarrow\ a^{\large n} = \dfrac{x_n}{x_0}$

so $\, x_1 = a x_0,\ x_2 = a x_1 = a^2 x_0,\,\ldots,\, x_n = a^n x_0$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+multiplicative+telescopy) for many more examples of multiplicative telescopy.